# Binding causes StackOverflow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Im not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Lets say, I have two UserControls `BoxA`and `BoxB`. Both have a DependencyProperty called `Text`

BoxB wraps BoxA which has a regular TextBox.

Binding should  work like this BoxB.Text <=> BoxA.Text <=> TextBox.Text

**Xaml BoxA:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SandBoxWpf.BoxA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

</UserControl>
```

**Xaml BoxB:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SandBoxWpf.BoxB"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SandBoxWpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <local:BoxA Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:BoxA>

</UserControl>
```

**Codebehind of both BoxA and BoxB**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SandBoxWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für BoxA.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BoxX : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Text",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(BoxX),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public BoxX()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="SandBoxWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SandBoxWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <local:BoxB Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Title}"></local:BoxB>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As soon as I type something into the BoxB i get a StackoverflowException.
If I remove the Mode=TwoWay or the UpdateSourceTrigger the StackOverflow is gone, but the binding doesnt work either.

Comment: Sounds like some form of infintie recursion. Could you show us your change notficiation code? There is a common recursion case (not detecting the same value is set).

Comment: @Christopher there is no code apart from the dependencyproperties.

Comment: When I used `UserControl` I usually set the DataContext in the code behind just after `InitlialiseComponents` give that a try and see if it works. BTW I think it's this: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` that is causing the issue.

Comment: @XAMlMAX same issue. However it works when I bind using code instead of Xaml.

Comment: Can you upload that to a git repo? I would like to reproduce that on my machine. And did you do it on both UCs? BoxA and BoxB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building a UserControl with bindable properties (i.e. dependency properties), you must **under no circumstances explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext**, be it to the control instance or to any private view model.

If you do that, a Binding like

```
<local:BoxB Text="{Binding Title}">
```

will no longer work. That Binding expects a Title property in the object in the current DataContext. The DataContext property value is usually inherited from the parent element of the UserControl, e.g. the Window. However, since you've explicitly set the DataContext, this mechanism is avoided.

This becomes particularly confusing with equally named properties in UserControls. When you write

```
<local:BoxA Text="{Binding Text, ...}"/>
```

in UserControl BoxB, your expectation is that the Binding source property is `BoxB.Text`. In fact it is `BoxA.Text`, because BoxA's DataContext is the BoxA instance.

---

So remove any

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

lines and write the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML with RelativeSource like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay},
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>

<local:BoxA Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay},
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
```

Comment: Ye this gets a little  messy because the bindingexpressions are much longer now. But atleast it works. I consider using an ElementName `_this` now instead. I hope this isnt problematic?!

Comment: You could also just set the DataContext of the top-level Panel in the UserControl, e.g. `<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">`

Answer (score 1):

With any form of Change Notificaiton, one danger is what I call the "Ping Pong" problem. Example:

1. Property A changes.
2. Property B is changed to match A.
3. Property B changed.
4. Property A is changed to match B.
5. Recurse to 1

In order to avoid that, the exampel code for Properties with Change notificaiton looks like this:

```
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get
    {
        return this.phoneNumberValue;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
        {
            this.phoneNumberValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If the input is the same as output, nothing is done. The squence goes:

1. Property A changes
2. Property B is chagned to match A
3. Proeprty B changes
4. Property A notices it already has that value anyway, so nothing is done.

My best guess is that WPF Elements have no such protection. It is one of those cases were "trying to be smart could result in being really dumb".

Comment: "WPF Elements have no such protection". Well, in fact they have, or at least dependency properties have. Assigning the same value to a dependency property again will not trigger its PropertyChangedCallback or any Binding.

Comment: @Clemens: "My best guess is that WPF Elements...". So apparently my guess was wrong.