# wpf bind user control property to viewmodel in usercontrol xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to the WPF development. I am updating an existing application and there seems to be a MVVM framework implemented.
Now I have a user control(ChartView.xaml) which has a dependency property:

```
public partial class ChartView : UserControl, IDisposable
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SceneProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Scene",
        typeof(IScene),
        typeof(ChartView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            default(IScene),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            ChartChangedCallback));

        public IScene Scene
        {
            get => (IScene)GetValue(SceneProperty);
            set => SetValue(SceneProperty, value);
        }
}
```

I want to bind this property to the viewModel and I was using following code in Xaml of **ChartView.xaml** to do so:

```
<local:ChartView
        x:Name="ChartView"
        Scene="{Binding Path=(viewModels:ChartViewModel.Scene)}"
        >
```

But the problem is that this code is recurrently calling the constructor on the user control as I get stackOverflow exception in "InitializeComponent()" method. Even if I remove the scene binding from xaml then also exception is there. As soon as I add

```
<local:ChartView>
```

I start getting stack overflow error.

Can anyone point out the correct way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268721/wpf-dependency-property

Comment: `Path=(viewModels:ChartViewModel.Scene)` denotes a static source property. It should just be `Path=Scene`, provided that the current DataContext holds an instance of ChartViewModel. For the StackOverflowException, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48707786/1136211

Comment: @Clemens, here I am trying to set the property binding for my user control from the xaml of the same user control

Comment: That's not what you're showing in your question. `<local:ChartView ...>` is not the XAML of ChartView.

Comment: Sorry if it mislead you, But it is xaml of ChartView, I am trying to add binding in the xaml of ChartView.xaml and my property is present in ChartView.xaml.cs

Comment: I have updated the question as well. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do, or that's not how things work! @Clemens

Comment: `<local:ChartView ...>` inside the XAML of a ChartView UserControl makes no sense. Please take a close look at the accepted answer to the duplicat question.

Comment: @Clemens I am unable o use anything that you have mentioned in that example. as my scene property is not available inside xaml to specify binding until I say <local:ChartView>.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the Scene property *inside* the UserControl's XAML? The only possible use is to bind a child element's property to it. If you want to bind the Scene property to a view model property, you have to do that *outside* of the UserControl's XAML, somewhere where you use the control, e.g. in your MainWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a StackOverflowException because you are creating an instance of your UserControl class inside its XAML, like

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace:ChartView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" ...>
    <local:ChartView .../>
</UserControl>
```

You should obviously not do that. Instead, bind the UserControl's Scene property to a view model property when you use it, e.g. in your MainWindow:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ChartViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       <local:ChartView Scene="{Binding Scene}"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

You may also create a default Style for your UserControl (e.g. in App.xaml), that sets up the Binding:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:ChartView">
        <Setter Property="Scene" Value="{Binding Scene}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I see that Its impossible to do something like what I was trying to do, I will have a add ome more layer of the user control in my application to create the binding, as I do not have access to window class. I just wanted to know weather or not it was possible to do without doing it inside the parent of the control.

Comment: @ManalGoyal You may use a Style to create the Binding. See the edited answer.

Comment: Why -1 on question